# upload file with php

Tags: php, file-upload, plupload

I'm using `plupload` to upload files to my webapp. I need to upload some xls files but upload fails for some of them. I have no ideea why the upload fails, but I get an error on `move_uploaded_file`.

I don't now why some upload files are not working. In the following are snippets of my code.

```
var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
  runtimes: 'html5,flash',
  containes: 'plupload',
  browse_button: 'browse',
  drop_element: 'droparea',
  url: 'include/myPlupload.php',
  flash_swf_url: 'javascripts/plupload/plupload.flash.swf',
  multipart: true,
  urlstream_upload: true,
  multipart_params:{directory: 'test'},
  max_file_size: '15mb', 
  filters:[
     { title: 'Spreadsheet', extensions: 'xls,xlsx,ods' }
  ]
 });
```

and parts of my PHP code, looks like this ....

```
error_reporting(-1);

// HTTP headers for no cache etc
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");

// ... ... 
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $new_path.$_FILES['file']['name'])){
   echo $html = '<div class="uploadedFile">'. basename($v) .'</div>';
} else {
   echo 'error on uploading file';
}
```

The problem is that upload fails on some files only. If I try to upload the same file from another computer that file upload succeeds but upload fails on other files.

Comment: Check the permission of directory.

Comment: What exactly does the error message from `move_uploaded_file` say? This might be a permission issue. Have you tried to change the permissions on the folder you are trying to upload to? Try `chmod 777 path/to/folder` from command line.

Comment: ...but don't forget to change it back later to some reasonable value.

Comment: now i use 777, but it no difference. some files fails to upload. $_FILES[error] is 1 and $_FILES[tmp_name] is empty.